# Trouble setting up Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

I have tried following the tutorial to send push notifications to Xamarin Android apps with Visual Studio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) but I have had **zero** success. I have no build errors, I am using the Xamarin Google Android Material nuget package for Xamarin 5 instead of the deprecated Xamarin Android Support libraries, but all I see on my Azure NotificationsHub metrics are incoming messages, supposedly from my test notifications.
Does this mean my app is failing the registration operation? I thought it was as simple as follows:

```
NotificationHub.SetListener(new AzureListener());

// Start the SDK
NotificationHub.Start(this.Application, HubName, ConnectionString);
```

but if there is a problem with my setup, how do I diagnose it? I expect to see a notification on either my phone or https://portal.azure.com/ but instead see nothing. There is no documentation on setup for Xamarin 5, so what do I do?

Comment: The code you provided was not able to reproduce this issue. You could refer to the sample in the link below for Azure Notification Hubs. https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin/tree/main/samples

Comment: My friend I know the code is correct but I need help to diagnose the problem

Comment: Only the code, i could not find what cause this issue. That's why i provide the link for you to check the steps.

Comment: The problem with this tutorial is it was last updated before Xamarin 5, so it is outdated. It references packages that are deprecated. You can't use it with Xamarin 5.

Comment: Also, the sample uses .NET2.0, which is no longer supported.

Comment: any success? I am having same problem and steps are not updated for VS 2022